# Google Sheets - Add note on edit when user edits only a portion of the sheet

Tags: google-sheets

This may be a simple answer, I'm very new to the script editor in google sheets.

I have about 8 sheets for individual users to enter data. I would like a note showing the last modified date on a range of cells in each of the 8 sheets. Each of the 8 sheets is identical in the layout. With the code below, I'm able to get a last modified date note on column 2, row 26, and it works great. However, I can't figure out how to expand that to include columns 2-7 and rows 26-35. I assumed just entering 2:7 under range.getRow() would work, but it does not.

Any suggestions on how to achieve this? Even better, ideally having just one comment note in a single cell on the sheet(L24 as an example), that shows the last modified date of any cell edited between columns 2-8 and rows 26-35?

My goal is really just to identify the last time a user has modified any cells within that specified range.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. The script is below.

```
    /**
 * The event handler triggered when editing the spreadsheet.
 * @param {Event} e The onEdit event.
 */
function onEdit(e) {
  // Set a comment on the edited cell to indicate when it was changed.
  var range = e.range;
  if(range.getRow() == 26 && range.getColumn() == 2){
        range.setNote('ROW: ' + range.getRow() + " COLUMN: "+ e.range.getColumn());
  range.setNote('Last modified: ' + new Date());
  }}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The OP wants to create a note in cell L24 on any sheet where the edited cell is in the range B26:H35 (columns 2 to 8 inclusive).

The OP's own code could create a note in the edited cell but was only configured for edits in the range "B26". However, most of the logic was in place, and only modest changes are required.

The points to note in this answer are:

- the Note is entered in cell "L24" of the edited sheet; this is made easier by defining a variable `noterange`.
- the row and column numbers for the edited range are assigned to variables; this makes it easier to use when building the IF statement.
- the edited range is assigned to a variable; this simplifies displaying the cell reference in the note.
- the IF statement is in two parts: it tests whether i) the edited row is between 26 and 35 AND ii) the edited column is between 2 and 8.
- the cell reference in the note is simplified by using `getA1Notation`.
- I left the date as used by the OP, but this can be shortened/simplified
- I inserted a line break between the range reference and "Date Modified" for easier reading
- I created an Installable onEdit Trigger

---

```
function so54658181(e) {

  // setup spreadsheet
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

  // get the active sheet
  var eactiveSheet = e.source.getActiveSheet();

  // set the location for the Note
  var noterange = eactiveSheet.getRange("L24");

  // get the edited cell and find the row and column numbers
  var erange = e.range;
  var editedRow = erange.getRow();
  var editedColumn = erange.getColumn()

  // if the row is between 26 and 35, and the column is between 2 and 8, then set the note
  if ((editedRow >= 26 && editedRow <= 35) && (editedColumn >= 2 && editedColumn <= 8)) {
     noterange.setNote("Cell " + erange.getA1Notation() + String.fromCharCode(10) + "Last modified: " + new Date());
  }

}
```

---

**Formatting the Date**

- Add these two line anywhere above the `IF` statement
  `// set date format
  var curDate = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT+1", "E, MMM dd yyyy");`
- Edit the following line of the IF statement; note that it now references `curDate`
  `noterange.setNote("Latest edit: Cell " + erange.getA1Notation() + String.fromCharCode(10) + "On: " + curDate);`
- A link to the most recent [Date and Time Patterns](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#formatdatedate-timezone-format) is included in the Google documentation.

Comment: Also, you mentioned you can edit the date string note. Can you elaborate, please? I would love for it to display the time in AM/PM, don't need the timezone stamp either, as all users are in central. Is this possible?

Comment: @Jason Did you add the Installable OnEdit trigger? I can't tell for sure from my end, but you'll note that I added some logger statements and these don't appear (nor the Execution Transcript) when I edited Capezio H26.

Comment: Thanks. I have not added an installable onEdit trigger. I'm not quite sure what that is, to be honest! This is all very new to me.. I'll do some google searches and see if I can figure it out, if not, i'll add another comment here. Thanks again, really appreciate this forum and you willingness to assist!

Comment: Figured out how to add the installable onEdit trigger. [link](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable)

Comment: Thanks again, @Tedinoz!

Comment: Last question - How do i edit the date/time to show AM/PM, rather than 24 hour? Minor edit, but it would be preferred. Thanks! @tedinoz

Comment: Done. Suggest you ensure that linked spreadsheet is suitable for public scrutiny.

Comment: After thinking through this, I'm starting to think rather than have the note placed in L24 showing any edit to the range B26:G35, I think it would be better to have the note in the field that was edited. This why I can see the last time each of the fields requiring user input was last edited. Can you help me with this last piece? I will post the link again in a second comment so that i can delete the link afterwards. Can't thank you enough for the help.

Comment: Substitute: `erange.setNote("Latest edit on: " + curDate);` for the action statement of the IF statement.

Comment: Thanks again for your help!

Comment: If you found the answer useful, then you might consider “accepting” it.

Comment: Thanks, @tedinoz - I wasn't sure how to do so, but just accepted it! Thanks